# Submission form using fields from DCTERMS registry

Tags: dspace

The wiki page on [Metadata and bitstream registries](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Metadata+and+Bitstream+Format+Registries) says the [following](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Metadata+and+Bitstream+Format+Registries#MetadataandBitstreamFormatRegistries-DublinCoreTermsRegistry(DCTERMS)) about the DCTERMS registry:

> The main advantage of the DCTERMS schema is that no field name details gets lost during harvesting, as opposed to harvesting of so called "simple" dublin core, where the qualifiers from the above schema are omitted during harvesting.

Any experience using this in custom submission forms defined in input-forms.xml? Does it mean that I can have an arbitrary value in a field's `dc-qualifier`, if `dc-schema` is "dcterms" and `dc-element` is a valid value from the DCTERMS schema?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that I can have an arbitrary value in a field's dc-qualifier, if dc-schema is "dcterms" and dc-element is a valid value from the DCTERMS schema?

Yes. Ignore the "dc-" bit in the input-forms.xml element names, you can have fields from any metadata schema in your submission form, as long as that field is listed in the metadata registry.

You may wish to keep in mind (also from the [Metadata and bitstream registries](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Metadata+and+Bitstream+Format+Registries#MetadataandBitstreamFormatRegistries-DublinCoreTermsRegistry%28DCTERMS%29) documentation):

> In DSpace 4, none of these fields are used by any of the system functionality out of the box.
>   The same is still true for DSpace 5, I believe.

Comment: Thanks. I think the key part is that the field needs to be in the metadata registry. In my specific case, none of the elements in DCTerms has a qualifier, so unless I extend the schema, `dc-qualifier` has to be empty.